# Incremental counter for <li> tags in XSLT

Tags: xslt, umbraco, counter

I'm using XSLT to pull some data from child nodes in an Umbraco (4.7) structure. That part is working fine, but I need to style each `<li>` item slightly different, so each one will be: `<li id=x>` where `x` is an integer between 1 and 15.

I've found a couple of methods for incrementing a counter value in XSLT, but I can't tell why it's not working as it should. Here's the relevant source:

```
<ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/Solutions/SolutionsItem[@isDoc]">
        <xsl:variable name="count">
            <xsl:number/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <li id="$count">
            <a><xsl:value-of select="solutionsItemTitle" /></a>
        </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

When I review the HTML's source after running the XSLT, it just shows `<li id=$count>` rather than an integer. Can anyone suggest where to go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an attribute value template `<li id="{$count}">...</li>` to compute the attribute value from the XPath expression.